# How to open a code behind file in visual studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Actually when we double click on the button we get the code behind file but I want to see it without double clicking on button.Actually I heard that we can open by solution explorer but I am not getting how exactly to open so I need your assistance in opening it.

Comment: Right click->view code?

Comment: 'F7' is shortcut key. Please search in google at-least one time.

Comment: Seriously guys??  You put this on hold for `professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration`?? Did any of you read the question??

Comment: This question is on-topic as it pertains a "programming tool".

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of ways of doing it...

- Right click in the mark-up file itself and choose `View Code`
- Right click on the mark-up file in Solution Explorer and choose `View Code`
- Click on the `Show All Files` button at the top of the Solution Explorer, then you can click on the <kbd>+</kbd>.  Then double click on code-behind file
- Pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> (see my comment below)

I see other people saying to use <kbd>F7</kbd>, which I presume will work. But as I've been using Visual Studio for a long time, and have it set to `Visual C++ 6` settings, `F7` does a rebuild for me... so can't confirm it

Answer (score 0):

Press F7 to view code, while in an .aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

Use below methods..

1. Right click on ASP.NET page and select view code..
2. You can also depend on Solution explorer..
   Click on page and select `name.cs`
3. Also use F7 to view code, while you are in an `name.aspx` file.